# Summoning Mobs With Players Rotation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft what command could I use to summon a mob facing the players direction?
So if I was facing north then when the pig (random example mob) spawned in it would face north as well.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact rotation (rather than what Darkchill Slayer answered) you summon it with a certain tag:

`/summon pig ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["Rotate"]}`

And in an always active repeat command block:

`tp @e[tag=Rotate] @p`

This will not only teleport to the same location, but also with the same rotation. After the repeat command block you should add a chain command block:

`scoreboard players tag @e[tag=Rotate] remove Rotate`

This prevents it from always teleporting to a player

Answer (score -1):

**You can do this by using /summon**

```
/summon Creeper ~ ~ ~ {Rotation:[90f,90f]}
```

If you want to spawn in a different direction, change the rotation angle tags (the 90 numbers)